# VBA code issue with Match and 2 matching criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use application.match function with 2 match criteria in VBA to return a row number where both criteria exist.  I can type directly into my worksheet and get the correct answer, but when converting to VBA code I receive a `type mismatch error (13)`.

This is what I type into the worksheet directly and get the correct row number returned:  `{=Match(1,("Criteria 1" = A:A)*("Criteria 2" = B:B),0)}`.  Criteria 1 and Criteria 2 are text strings.  Data within column A and column B are a mixture of text and numbers.

This is the equivalent code I tried in VBA which resulted in Type mismatch error:

```
Result = application.match(1,(Criteria 1 = Range("A:A"))*(Criteria 2 = Range("B:B")), 0)
```

Tried a shorter test line, and also got type mismatch error:

```
Test = Application.match(1,(Criteria 1 = Range("A:A"),0)
```

I expected this code to return the row number (Result) where both Criteria 1 and Criteria 2 existed.  The Locals window shows that Criteria 1 is a Variant/String.  I tried a cut down version of the code, and got similar error.  The result in this case was Test, and the Locals window showed that Test type was Variant/Double, Criteria1 was Variant/String and Range("A:A") is Variant/Variant (I assigned Range(A:A) to a variable to determine this)

Comment: Please format the code parts as code block.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original formula via `Evaluate`

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim m As Variant, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'for example

    m = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=MATCH(1,(""Criteria 1"" = A:A)*(""Criteria 2"" = B:B),0)")

    Debug.Print IIf(IsError(m), "No match!", m)

End Sub
```

**NOTE**: use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method - if you use `Application.Evaluate` then your formula will be evaluated in the context of whichever sheet happens to be active, which may not be the sheet you want.

EDIT: adding variables into your formula

```
Sub Tester2()

    Const FRMLA As String = "=MATCH(1,(""<c1>"" = <r1>)*(""<c2>"" = <r2>),0)"

    Dim m As Variant, sht As Worksheet, f As String
    Dim c1 As String, c2 As String, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'for example

    'specify the formula inputs
    Set rng1 = sht.Range("A:A")
    Set rng2 = sht.Range("B:B")
    c1 = "Criteria 1"
    c2 = "Criteria 2"

    'replace the tokens in the formula
    f = Replace(FRMLA, "<c1>", c1)
    f = Replace(f, "<c2>", c2)
    f = Replace(f, "<r1>", rng1.Address(False, False))
    f = Replace(f, "<r2>", rng2.Address(False, False))

    m = sht.Evaluate(f)

    Debug.Print IIf(IsError(m), "No match!", m)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your suggested code worked.  Any insight into why my original code does not work?

Comment: You're mixing VBA and worksheet formula syntax - it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I believe I need the VBA syntax as ultimately what I am trying to do is pass in the match criteria from an array AND pass in the search column/range within a loop.  I messed around with the evaluate method, but can't get it to accept variables.

Comment: Evaluate will accept variables, but they need to be concatenated into the final formula string which Evaluate operates on.  If you update your question with what you tried I can suggest some fixes.

Comment: Worked great.  I am not familiar with the < > Syntax.  I tried searching but only came up with not equal.  Can you point me to what this syntax is called so that I can read up on it?

Comment: Those `<>` are not syntax - just there to delimit the tokens for replacement.  They have no special meaning